# ViaMichelin.com city hashes

Tags: php, geolocation, maps, routes

I need to calculate route between 2 cities (1 dynamic,1 static) via www.viamichelin.com (because they cover my area, eastern europe). AFAIK api calls are not free, so I must find other solution.

Each city (place) has it's own unique hash (which I manually entered in DB)... eg Sarajevo, Bosnia.
http://pokit.etf.ba/upload/pokit09b69adcd7cbae914c6204984097d2da.png

I can find this hashes in URL if I enter city name manually, but I was wondering if anyone has some kind of hash database he wishes to share :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.viamichelin.co.uk/tpl/psg/divers/htm/legalnotice.htm

> General 
>  Unless expressly
>   authorised in advance by ViaMichelin,
>   all reproduction, representation and
>   use other than that stated above is
>   prohibited, in particular: 
>   ....
>  any extraction or reuse,
>   including for private purposes, of a
>   substantial part of the content of the
>   databases created by the Website;

Comment: I use hashes just to generate link to viamichelin.com (http://www.viamichelin.com/web/Itineraires?strStartLocid=31NDIxZzMxMGNORE11T0RVNU1UWT1jTVRndU5ETXpPRGs9&strDestLocid=31NDIxOHgxMGNORFF1TnpVek16Zz1jTVRjdU1UWTVOams9), is that a problem?

Comment: @Webarto: That's no longer only a programming problem, check with your lawyer(s) (who may wish to check with Michelin's lawyers). IANAL, but it *could* be interpreted as "yes that's a problem, we are suing and also you now owe us $$$".